# get the value after decimal point in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript number 12.1542. and I want the new string 12.(1542*60) from this string.

How can I get it.
Thanks

Comment: where does this `*60` come from?

Comment: Should the new string be `12.92520` or `"12.(1542*60)"` (literally)?

Answer (score 29):

You could use the [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_%28Modulus%29):

```
var num = 12.1542;
console.log(num % 1);
```

However, due to the nature of floating point numbers, you will get a number that is very slightly different. For the above example, Chrome gives me `0.15419999999999945`.

Another (slightly longer) option would be to use `Math.floor` and then subtract the result from the original number:

```
var num = 12.1542;
console.log(num - Math.floor(num));​
```

Again, due to the nature of floating point numbers you will end up with a number that is very slightly different than you may expect.

Comment: You can also use toFixed(X) fix the number: `console.log((num - Math.floor(num)).toFixed(2));`

Answer (score 1):

Input sanity checks aside, this should work:

```
var str = '12.1542';
var value = Math.floor( str ) + ( 60 * (str - Math.floor( str ) ) );
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis, but if you add it in, this results in `21.251999999999967`, which I don't think is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thx. Added the parenthesis. I think, almost nobody here is completly sure, what the op really wants :-)

Answer (score 1):

Time to decimals:

```
function toDec(sec){
    var itg=Math.floor(sec);
    sec=(sec-itg)*60;
    return itg+sec; // OR: return new String(itg+sec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**floor** is probably the method to get what you want:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp

You could also use **ceil**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp

Comment: This would get you the part *before* the decimal point, not after.

Comment: @limelights: good point. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Answer (score 0):

```
let Decimal = "12.56"

Decimal.substring(Decimal.indexOf(".")+1, Decimal .length)

// answer is 56.
```